session_id saved in session_store is different to request.session[:session_id]
Ruby 3.2.4, Rails 7.1.3.2, Postgres 14, Ubuntu 22.04.
gem 'activerecord-session_store'
initializer is as follows
Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store, :key => '_my_app_session'

The session id being stored in the database sessions table is
2::026c0fe81b8054c767dea472b0e5ac1f61dc3412b78bd88409c0f23845b03093

The session_id in request.session[:session_id] is
45eaf5901a0a50f003ba743a17e89c22

Why are they different?  I need to be able to access the session record - how do I find out what the session_id in the sessions table is?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78335723/207090

That's it - thanks - my searching skills obviously lacking.  If you post as answer I can accept and upvote.
